# Is there a way to enable the object class to control the gtk window initialized by the another object class?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have class which handle my glade file and initialize it , other methods interact with user .

what I want is to write another class wthich control the veiwing options (like locate themes , locate icons ) of the glade file already initialized .

I use  all kinds of building (including inheritance)  I know ,  but I got multiple errors (like the varible x is not defined ) .
in best condition I got this error : when the second class act ; it initialize the glade file from the start causing another window to appear , set the options for the second window , leave the original window unchanged .

this a peice of code which cause this error:

first class:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.builder = gtk.Builder()

    self.glade_file = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()) + '/glade_files/mainwin.glade'
    self.builder.add_from_file(self.glade_file)

    self.win=self.builder.get_object('window1')
    options()
    self.win.show()
    ................ and so on .
```

second class :

```
class options():
    .... some methods then 
    def icon_options():
        builder=gtk.Builder()
        a=os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()) + '/glade_files/mainwin.glade'
        builder.add_from_file(a)
        image=builder.get_object('image5')
        print image
        image.set_from_file('apple.png')
```

Is ther is a way to enable the second class to control the window initialized by the first class ??

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: I want to enable the second class (options) to access the first class variable (builder) i.e I want the second class to control the themes of the window initialized by the first class ...

Comment: what I got is another window with the options specified , I paste this code here and I know it do this unwanted action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A posible solution is to add in the second class 'options', a reference to the window created in the first class. So you can access the member of the window. You can pass this object in the constructor of the second class, something like:

In the first class:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.builder = gtk.Builder()

    # some code here ...

    self.win = self.builder.get_object('window1')
    options(self.win)
    self.win.show()
```

Second class:

```
class options():
    def __init__(self, window):
        self._window = window

    # do whatever you want with the window ...
```